# Función que reciba cadena y un número y devuelva otra con los últimos caracteres

Tags: java

Os explico, el ejercicio anterior era el siguiente:

> Realiza una función que reciba una cadena y un número y devuelva otra
>   cadena con los primeros caracteres de la cadena, tantos como indique
>   el parámetro. No se puede utilizar el método `substring`. Por ejemplo,
>   si recibe "Programación" y 5, devuelve "Progr".

Y mi código, creo que está bien porque me funciona es este:

```
String cad1 = "Renacuajo", cad2 = "";
int longitud = 5;

for(int i = 0; i < longitud; i++) {
  cad2 = cad2 + cad1.charAt(i);
}

System.out.println(cad2);
```

Me devuelve "Renac" por lo que estaría bien. Mi duda es en el siguiente, en vez de devolverme "Renac" me tiene que devolver "cuajo". No se puede usar `substring`. Creo que no debe ser muy distinto al anterior pero no sabría como ponerlo sin usar `substring`.

Comment: Tengo una duda sobre tu duda: El enunciado cambió y necesitas los cinco últimos? Si es así, puedes recorrer la cadena en orden inverso

Answer (score 2):

En ese caso debe iniciar en `cad.length - longitud` y que el final sea el resto de la cadena

```
String cad1 = "Renacuajo", cad2 = "";
int longitud = 5;
for(int i = cad1.length() - longitud; i < cad1.length(); i++) {
    cad2 = cad2 + cad1.charAt(i);
}

System.out.println(cad2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que necesitas es mostrar los cinco últimos caracteres, puedes recorrer la cadena en orden inverso. Vas desde la última posición hasta la primera, mantienes un contador para el recorrido que decrece y otro para la cadena de salida, que aumenta.
Terminas de añadir carácteres cuando el contador de salida llega al tamaño límite:

```
String cad1 = "Renacuajo", cad2 = "";
int longitud = 5;
int counter;

for(int i = cad.length() - 1, counter = 1; i = 0; i--, counter++) {
    if (counter > longitud) { 
        break; 
    }
    cad2 = cad2 + cad1.charAt(i);
}

System.out.println(cad2);
```